# Webpack-Hot-Middleware not working with HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: express, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-hot-middleware

Hot module reloading is not working with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. I can actually see in console that my files are getting updated but browser does not render updated application.

#### Relevant Links

Repository: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/tree/ssr
Server File: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/blob/ssr/server.js

Webpack Base: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/blob/ssr/webpack.common.js

Webpack Dev: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/blob/ssr/webpack.dev.js

Package.json: https://github.com/developer239/workbox-webpack-react/blob/ssr/package.json

### Environment

npm 4.2.0

node 7.10.0

I am trying to figure this one out for hours. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by official `webpack-hot-middleware` documentation. Hot middleware client must be in the same entry.

I replaced this:

```
  entry: {
    hot: 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?http://localhost:3000',
    app: './src/index.js',
  },
```

With this:

```
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?http://localhost:3000',
    './src/index.js',
  ],
```